# Pandas dataframe use columns as rows (melt)

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I know, this questions has been asked several times, but I didn't manage to build my solution based on those already asked.

**DF I have:**

```
id| country  |  series name   | 2015 | 2016 | 2017
--+----------+----------------+------+------+------
0 | saudi    | fertility rate | 1    | 2    | 2   |    
1 | saudi    | CO2 emissions  | 5    | 10   | 15  | 
2 | pakistan | fertility rate | 1    | 2    | 1   |
3 | pakistan | CO2 emissions  | NaN  | NaN  | NaN |
```

**DF I want:**

```
id| country  | year | fertility rate | CO2 emissions 
--+----------+------+----------------+---------
0 | saudi    | 2015 |       1        |    5      
1 | saudi    | 2016 |       2        |    10      
2 | saudi    | 2017 |       2        |    15      
3 | pakistan | 2015 |       1        |    NaN
4 | pakistan | 2016 |       2        |    NaN
5 | pakistan | 2017 |       1        |    NaN
```

I tried multiple different melt configurations, but somehow I am not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you make data source easy to copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC `melt` + `pivot_table`.  This answer assumes that `id` is your index.  If it is not, just drop it, as it is not needed in the calculation.

---

```
d = df.melt(id_vars=["country", "series name"], var_name="year")

d.pivot_table(
    index=["country", "year"], columns="series name", values="value"
).reset_index()
```

```
series name   country  year  CO2 emissions  fertility rate
0            pakistan  2015            NaN             1.0
1            pakistan  2016            NaN             2.0
2            pakistan  2017            NaN             1.0
3               saudi  2015            5.0             1.0
4               saudi  2016           10.0             2.0
5               saudi  2017           15.0             2.0
```

Comment: Thank you @user3483203! This helped me after you posted 2 years.